# multiple Redis instances handling chat servers

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io, scaling

I am designing a chat app that uses node.js as its backend. For best scaling, i intend to have multiple node servers running in parallel and intend to have them connected through a redis cache server for passing messages for users that are not on the same server (using redis's publish and subscribe channels).

The thing that i don't like is that i'm actually using a single redis server for this scenario.

How can i use a cluster of redis servers and having them communicate on the same channels? I would like to have a dynamic option to better handle future redis-server scaling out.

Comment: [Redis Cluster](http://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial)?